# What sort of snake does this code make?

Tags: android, coordinates

I'm sure someone out there can answer this in a matter of seconds...
All I am wondering is if this piece of code is read from bottom to top? The comments say the snake is initially heading east then heads NORTH and when I run it, this statement is true.
But the coordinates go from 7,7 to 6,7 then 5,7 and so on...is that not a west bound snake? or is the code read from bottom to top?
Here is the piece of code.

```
private void initNewGame() {
    mSnakeTrail.clear();
    mAppleList.clear();

    // For now we're just going to load up a short default eastbound snake
    // that's just turned north


    mSnakeTrail.add(new Coordinate(7, 7));
    mSnakeTrail.add(new Coordinate(6, 7));
    mSnakeTrail.add(new Coordinate(5, 7));
    mSnakeTrail.add(new Coordinate(4, 7));
    mSnakeTrail.add(new Coordinate(3, 7));
    mSnakeTrail.add(new Coordinate(2, 7));
    mNextDirection = NORTH;
```

Answer (score 3):

Code is never read from bottom to top, at least in Java. It only means that snake is added from head to tail and not vice versa. Also, three or more, use a **for** :)

Comment: I may quote you on that later

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing adding the *tail* coordinates with progressing the snake.  If the snake is heading East, it's tail will trail off in a Westerly direction.

Answer (score 0):

No, procedures/methods in Java (and most other languages, to my knowledge) are read from the top down. So the first thing executed when entering `InitNewGame()` is `mSnakeTrail.clear()`, then `mAppleList.clear()`, etc.